# Getting exception when trying to access class member with address

Tags: c++

I am trying to access class variable that created in heap with address in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class class2 {
private:
    string String = "x";
public:
    void function() {
        cout<<String;
    }
};

class class1 {
public:
    class2* i;
        void  address(class2* x) {
        i = x;
    }
};



int main() {
    int len;
    cin>>len;
    class1 **Class1 = new class1*[len];

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        Class1[i] = new class1[i];
    }

    Class1[0]->address(Class1[0]->i);
    Class1[0]->i->function();

}
```

---

```
void function() {
        cout<<String;
    }
```

if I change this to this I get no errors and it works fine. So I thought there is a problem about accessing string variable.

```
void function() {
        cout<<"x";
    }
```

Exception thrown: read access violation.
std::_String_alloc > >::_Get_data(...) returned 0xDDDDDDDD.

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
class class2 {
private:
    string String = "x";
public:
    string function() {
        return String;
    }
};

class class1 {
public:
    string String;
    class2* i;
        void  address(class2* x) {
        x = new class2();
        i = x;
    }

        void function(string x) {
            String = x;
    }
};



int main() {
    int len;
    cin>>len;
    class1 **Class1 = new class1*[len];

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        Class1[i] = new class1[i];
    }

    Class1[0]->address(Class1[0]->i);
    Class1[0]->function(Class1[0]->i->function());
    cout<<Class1[0]->String;

}
```

> Exception thrown at 0x0F4D514F (vcruntime140d.dll) in Project70.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xDDDDDDDD.

Comment: `Class1[0]->address(Class1[0]->i);`....`Class1[0]->i` is not initialized there (it was never created). You could do: `Class1[0]->address(new class2);`

Comment: It worked thanks. But I don't understand why parameter is wrong.

Comment: @HüseyinBeraBulut Because `Class1[0]->i` hasn't been initialized yet before you pass it to `Class1[0]->address()`, which initializes `Class1[0]->i`.  Kind of a chicken&egg scenario. Before calling `address()`, `Class1[0]->i` has an indeterminate value, and after `address()` exits, `Class1[0]->i` still has an indeterminate value.  So calling `Class1[0]->i->function()` afterwards passes an invalid `this` pointer to `function()`, which is why the code crashes trying to access `this->String`.

Comment: Why Class[0]->i has still indeterminate value after calling address() ?

Comment: Pointers need to point to valid memory before they can be dereferenced. You never assign `Class1[0]->i` to point to anything valid. The `address()` function basically does nothing as you are assigning `Class1[0]->i = Class1[0]->i` - since that is what you pass as a parameter to the function.

Comment: PS. The value `0xDDDDDDDD` is a hint that you are using an uninitialized value. See: [When and why will an OS initialise memory to 0xCD, 0xDD, etc. on malloc/free/new/delete?](//stackoverflow.com/q/370195)

Comment: I updated the code can you look at it?